# Phalcon 3 and Swift Mailer

Tags: phalcon, swiftmailer

I want to integrate Swift Mailer in Phalcon 3 using dependency injection. I have already seen various ways to do solve this issue in Phalcon and Phalcon 2.

It would be great if you can help me with this issue.

Comment: Nothing with using external libraries has changed in version 3. The examples for 1 and 2 are still valid.

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov Please direct me to an example. I am a novice when it comes to Phalcon Framework.

Comment: " I have already seen various ways to do solve this issue in Phalcon and Phalcon 2." Go see them again :)

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov Alright, thanks for your time.

Comment: "But I was unable to make something out of it." what have **you** tried? **show us your code**

Comment: @Timothy I tried to set things up as in the project Vokuro in my project. https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro

Comment: @Timothy I was searching for a code in controllers of Vokuro project which would allow me to send an email in my controller.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/phalcon-ext/mailer. It's a mailer wrapper for SwiftMailer and Phalcon.

Comment: @Timothy Yes, I have seen it. But I dont know how to use it. It would be great if you could give me some instructions on how to integrate it with my project and use it in my controller.

Comment: did you follow the install instructions? if not, **follow them**. If you want, I can copy and paste the instructions here, but that would just be silly. After you followed the installation process, try the example code. If you get errors along the way, [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42850965/edit) with the errors.

Comment: @Timothy thanks, I found a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://github.com/phalcon-ext/mailer and follow its instruction and you will get a working solution to send emails through Swift Mailer in Phalcon 3.

That being said there were a few issues which I had to tackle to get things up. So here is a list of changes that you have to make on your end:

- If you are going to use smtp then change the **port to 587** and **encryption to tls**
- Apart from it you are going to face error from google and it will send a security alert to attached gmail id. In the security email which I received; I clicked on **allowing access to less secure apps**
- And then it took me to a google sign-in page where I was able to lower security by allowing less secure apps to access my gmail account.
- There might be a better way to send email without lowering security access. If you find one then please let me know.
- The github page says to add in your code **require_once('vendor/autoload.php');** you can do it in **index.php located inside the public folder**.